# Model-level errors in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I appear to have missed something very simple, but can't find the answer anywhere.

I want to generate a generic "You've got errors -- see below" type of statement atop a form when any errors exist using `@Html.ValidationSummary(true)`, and list all the specific errors only inline next to the relevant fields. I want the logic and the error text contained in an Action Filter.

The problem is, all the documentation I've seen on "model-level" errors explains how to display them in views, but not how to *add* them to the model state.

Errors added via `ModelState.AddModelError` are not model-*level*  - so how can I do I add a model-level error?

Comment: if you match the key to the input name, they'll be model level.

Comment: I can't exactely see what do you mean by "model-level". ModelState.AddModelError are for model errors.

Comment: If the model property equals the name of the key the error will be attached to the specific property. If the key is empty it will be global model level.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`ModelState.AddModelError` will work. Just set the key with an empty string.

```
ModelState.AddModelError(String.Empty, "here is the error");
```